# Can't click the check box in the sign up page

Tags: selenium, testng

I am writing selenium script for Autotrader.com signup page. I am not able to click on 'I Agree' Check box. This is what I have written:

```
WebElement cboxlink = driver.findElement(By.id("j_id_29-j_id_2h-"
        +                  "myatcRegisterForm-j_id_3n-acceptTerms"));

cboxlink.click();
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="j_id_3n" class="atcui atcui-form-row atcui-clearfix atcui-small terms" style="">
<input id="j_id_29-j_id_2h-myatcRegisterForm-j_id_3n-acceptTerms" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true" name="j_id_29-j_id_2h-myatcRegisterForm-j_id_3n-acceptTerms">
<label for="j_id_29-j_id_2h-myatcRegisterForm-j_id_3n-acceptTerms">
I accept terms of the
<a target="_blank" href="/privacy.jsp">Privacy Statement</a> 
and <a target="_blank" href="/legal/visitor-agreement.xhtml">Visitor Agreement</a>.
</label>
```

Comment: Please add the html.

Comment: Is an exception thrown or it just doesn't appear to do anything?

Comment: after entering confirm password it is not able to find that check box. its showing this

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException

Comment: <div id="j_id_3n" class="atcui atcui-form-row atcui-clearfix atcui-small terms" style="">
<input id="j_id_29-j_id_2h-myatcRegisterForm-j_id_3n-acceptTerms" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true" name="j_id_29-j_id_2h-myatcRegisterForm-j_id_3n-acceptTerms">
<label for="j_id_29-j_id_2h-myatcRegisterForm-j_id_3n-acceptTerms">
I accept terms of the
<a target="_blank" href="/privacy.jsp">Privacy Statement</a>
and
<a target="_blank" href="/legal/visitor-agreement.xhtml">Visitor Agreement</a>
.

Comment: Did you try to wait until the check box is clickable? Maybe there is some other element that is transparent but is over all the page that disappears after a little time and you don't see it but the code runs too quickly for that element to disappear?